# Visual Studio - NuGet Packages keep getting removed or deleted whenever I open Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

So I have installed an Excel Data Reader in VS's NuGet package manager. After installation everything works fine and my code run's smoothly. After I have finished coding for the night I save my work and then commit my changes to sourcetree.

The next day, I open up my project again and at the top of the form the part where I state what I'm using (I don't know what they are called I'm only a beginner, but I'll put an example of what I mean below)

```
using Excel;
using System;
```

etc. etc.

There is a red line under Excel and it says:

***A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; Excel is not a namespace. Consider using a 'using static' directive instead.***

And then further down the code when I use methods from the package it says

***The type or namespace name 'IExcelDataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?***

Or

***The name 'ExcelReaderFactory' does not exist in the current context***

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package and using the static directive but none of it works, even though the same code was working the night before, it's just when I save it to sourcetree this happens. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you under your project add it as reference?

Comment: There is no reference for it

Comment: what package have you installed, ExcelDataReder?.

Comment: I have installed ExcelDataReader (Version 2.1.2.3) by ExcelDataReader

Comment: Then you should use: using ExcelDataReader; you can give your namespace an specific name if you want. I cannot say why it worked yesterday and not now since i haven't seen the code

Comment: There is no namespace for using ExcelDataReader, when it was working, there would only be a namespace for Excel

Comment: Just tested it here works perfect with: using ExcelDataReader ;.. Can you link an image ?

Comment: No I can't I've reverted back to a original commit but I will try if It happens next time